# How does Laravel API and Passport work together?

Tags: php, laravel, web, laravel-passport

So i am currently developing a web app that will use laravel api for future mobile use and laravel passport. My passport is set up to where i used postman to login, register, and delete an account, the usual functions. The laravel API also works independently as can make the requests from my routes.

Using Passport, i log in, and it returns a token, in which if i am correct,  is the token that will be used for the API. Now upon creating the api, which will be accepting the forms/parameter to the main function for my app, **How do i use the token i received from Passport with the API?**

In the request to the API do i need to ask for the user's token and if so how to check that its a token that can be used from my application. It's this middle part of connecting them i cannot understand, as I can make the passport work by itself, and the laravel api by itself that im just sending the posts/get from postman  and getting my json responses that ill use later for my js frontend.

Comment: Check my below answer.

Answer (score 0):

In `config/auth.php` replace `api` -> `driver` to `password`, and consequently you can use the same `Auth::user()` method to login through Password API tokens. Don't forget to pass the token as `Authorization` header from front-end side wi the key `Bearer`.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. You just need to install passport and then you will get client secret key.
> 2. Then you need call API using passport default route like **http://192.000.0.000:8000/oauth/token**  with some parameters like:

```
client_id = 1,
client_secret = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
grant_type = client_credentials
username = hanna.stracke@example.org
password = secret
scope = *
```

> 3. Then hit the URL then you will get "access_token". using access_token you will login the user.

Thanks,

Comment: Does every route within the api route group with middleware: I.E Route::group(['prefix' => 'api', 'middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {
}); need to have a table in the DB with api_token included inside as a field? say i have my users field, have the token, its passed thru and allows me to use the routes in the group. Now i add another route that uses a different controller for "tasks", does that task table also need to have api_token in the table fields ?